# Java SWT Key, MouseWheel Listener

Tags: swt, keylistener, mousewheel

I added a "KeyListener" to Shell for changing FullScreen or not.
Also I added a "MouseWheelListener" to GLCanvas for changing its depth.

But there is a problem that if I enable the KeyLisetner in Shell, the MouseWheelListener doesn't work.
If I disable the other one, the KeyListener doesn't work either.

What may cause it?

code: 
http://codepad.org/4V5ExY27      shell
http://codepad.org/BYnTWlMf      mouse wheel

thanks.

Comment: I solve it. Adding the same KeyListener to GLCanvas could work.

Comment: Then add an answer to your question and mark it as the solution.